# Как восстановить базу данных mysql имея только папку data?

Tags: php, mysql

Удалили папку с xampp. Есть только папка data, которая находится в папке mysql. Загрузил эту папку на гитхаб - https://github.com/gpr-xirdalan/mysqldata Как восстановить данные?

Comment: поставить обратно xampp или той же версии mysql и подпихнуть ему эту вашу папку